# Rewrite rule break css on third level links

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have trying to make pretty url's with `.htaccess`. The structure of the pages is like this- `http://example.com/category_id=1/item_id=1`:

```
index
index->category
index->category->single_item_from_category
```

I've trying to make this like-`http://example.com/category-1/item-1.html` but the css on the third level where is `/item-1.html` isn't there. Is like the page doesn't have css at all.
I must say that this site is in sub folder of main sait: `http://example/site-is-here/`
This is the .htaccess code

```
RewriteRule ^vcat-([^/]*)/video-([^/]*)\.html$ /second/video_category.php?video_cat_id=$1&video_id=$2 [L]
```

and this is the link in the php/html part

```
<a href="/vcat-'.$video_cat_id.'/video-'.$row['video_id'].'.html">'.$row['video_title'].'</a>
```

on all other pages those 'pretty url's' are working. The problem is only whit pages that are like this `index.php/category/item`

When I go on the page which seems to miss css fail and check in source of the page the link to the css is: `http://example.com/sait/vcat/css/main.css`
but should be
`http://example.com/sait/css/main.css`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `base href` in your `<head></head>` section like this:

```
<base href="http://www.example.com/sub-folder/" />
```

It should work.

Comment: Thank's for the answer

Comment: This will only work if the link to the CSS is relative, however, the OP states: "check in source of the page the link to the css is: `http://example.com/sait/vcat/css/main.css`" - which would seem to suggest that the server-side script is building the URL incorrectly?

Comment: @w3d I don't know what exactly happen but when I add this `base href` it all work now.